Setting up a Garry's mod TTT Server with the Moat Setup - Lua Errors
So i have been trying to setup a TTT Server running the moat addon uploaded by moat - The upload is however very old, this is the github https://github.com/colemclaren/ttt
I have been trying to get it to work. But just can't seem to get the code to work, these are the current things i have done.

Installing TTT-Master
Updating mysqloo to newest version
installing tmysql4 in garrysmod/lua/bin (Tmysql4 was called in garrysmod/lua/dash/libraries/server/mysql.lua
configuring top part of addons/moat_addons/lua/system/cfg/sql/sv_config.lua to be configured to my database

Looking at the console i still have many errors. However it did solve a fair few. I saw it write some tables to the database but there is still a lot missing from the full addon. I don't have a inventory ingame, chat function is broken, Item system is broken and it's spewing lua errors in the ingame console aswell.
Here is the ones i see from the server console.
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: [moat_addons] addons/moat_addons/lua/_dev/init.lua:3: attempt to index global 'yugh' (a nil value) 1. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/_dev/init.lua:3 2. include - [C]:-1 3. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607 4. include - [C]:-1 5. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: [moat_addons] addons/moat_addons/lua/system/cfg/discord/sv_webhooks.lua:45: attempt to index global 'slack' (a nil value) 1. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/cfg/discord/sv_webhooks.lua:45 2. include - [C]:-1 3. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607 4. include - [C]:-1 5. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: [moat_addons] addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/include.lua:13: attempt to index global 'yugh' (a nil value) 1. load - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/include.lua:13 2. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/include.lua:34 3. include - [C]:-1 4. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607 5. include - [C]:-1 6. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/ux/core/palette.lua:62: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/datastore.lua:49: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: [moat_addons] addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/datastore.lua:65: attempt to call field 'sql' (a nil value) 1. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/datastore.lua:65 2. include - [C]:-1 3. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607 4. include - [C]:-1 5. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/assets/weapon_sounds.lua:3396: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/d3a/server/_commands/forcemotd.lua:132: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/d3a/server/sv_commands.lua:80: in function 'Load' addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/d3a/server/sv_commands.lua:90: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/d3a/server/sv_player_checkpass.lua:195: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/mapvote/core/sv_mapvote.lua:85: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/mapvote/prevent/init.lua:62: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/chat/sv_logger.lua:20: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/chat/sv_logger.lua:32: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/deathmsgs/chatmsg/sv_notify.lua:3: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/deathmsgs/chatmsg/sv_notify.lua:7: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/deathmsgs/chatmsg/sv_notify.lua:17: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/hit/sv_ahr.lua:187: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/inv2/init.lua:65: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/inv2/shared/sh_omegas.lua:181: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/inv2/ass/paints/sh_testskin.lua:38: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/inv2/ass/seasonal/easter/sv_moateaster.lua:124: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/scoreboard/levels/sv_level_color.lua:43: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/sessions/sv_servers.lua:18: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/terrortown/hs_sound_sv.lua:3: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/terrortown/hs_sound_sv.lua:13: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/terrortown/sv_buddy_damage.lua:11: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/weapons/sh_vm.lua:5: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607: in main chunk [C]: in function 'include' addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: [ERROR] AddCSLuaFile: Couldn't find 'weapons/gmod_tool/shared.lua'
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: bad argument #3 to hook.Add (function expected, got nil) stack traceback: addons/moat_addons/lua/entities/peace_sentry/init.lua:83: in main chunk
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: Refusing to load ttt_ending_slow_motion because it is missing Type and Base keys!

05/28/2024 - 15:58:27: Lua Error: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/sessions/sv_servers.lua:125: attempt to call field 'mysql' (a nil value) stack traceback: [C]: in function 'mysql' addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/sessions/sv_servers.lua:125: in function <addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/sessions/sv_servers.lua:121> lua/dlib/modules/hook.lua:904: in function 'Run' addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/datastore.lua:36: in function <addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/datastore.lua:26> [C]: at 0x7185a8d0 lua/dlib/modules/hook.lua:904: in function <lua/dlib/modules/hook.lua:900>
05/28/2024 - 15:58:27: Lua Error: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/inv2/server/sv_tabs_bounties.lua:269: attempt to index a nil value stack traceback: [C]: in function '__index' addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/inv2/server/sv_tabs_bounties.lua:269: in function <addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/inv2/server/sv_tabs_bounties.lua:267> [C]: at 0x7185a8d0 lua/dlib/modules/hook.lua:904: in function <lua/dlib/modules/hook.lua:900>
05/28/2024 - 15:58:27: Lua Error: addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/inv2/server/sv_tabs_bounties.lua:320: attempt to index a nil value stack traceback: [C]: in function '__index' addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/inv2/server/sv_tabs_bounties.lua:320: in function <addons/moat_addons/lua/plugins/moat/modules/inv2/server/sv_tabs_bounties.lua:319> [C]: at 0x7185a8d0 lua/dlib/modules/hook.lua:904: in function <lua/dlib/modules/hook.lua:900>

05/28/2024 - 15:58:28: Lua Error: [moat_addons] addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/yugh/extensions/http.lua:58: attempt to call upvalue 'Struct' (a nil value) 1. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/yugh/extensions/http.lua:58

This one is probably safe to ignore for now - this seems to be because i haven't connected the discord webhooks yet - but can easily be done.
05/28/2024 - 15:58:25: Lua Error: [moat_addons] addons/moat_addons/lua/system/cfg/discord/sv_webhooks.lua:45: attempt to index global 'slack' (a nil value) 1. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/cfg/discord/sv_webhooks.lua:45 2. include - [C]:-1 3. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607 4. include - [C]:-1 5. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4

So given the fact installation isn't really documented i could only hope that i could get it to work like it was back in the day on moat. But i don't know if this is just horrible outdated.
I have tried the steps i wrote earlier - I have also tried adding this https://github.com/SuperiorServers/dash which is the newest version of dash that i could find. It made no changes or maybe gave more errors hard to judge ^^
I don't know exactly what to do. I don't know if is the dependencies that are outdated or what exactly is the issue for it not working. So i am at a loss - Hopefully one of you can help, i would appreciate it greatly!
